# Are polymorphic variables allowed?

Tags: rust

I have various structs that all implement the same trait. I want to branch on some condition, deciding at runtime which of those structs to instantiate. Then, regardless of which branch I followed, I want to call methods from that trait.

Is this possible in Rust? I'm hoping to achieve something like the following (which does not compile):

```
trait Barks {
    fn bark(&self);
}

struct Dog;

impl Barks for Dog {
    fn bark(&self) {
        println!("Yip.");
    }
}

struct Wolf;

impl Barks for Wolf {
    fn bark(&self) {
        println!("WOOF!");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let animal: Barks;
    if 1 == 2 {
        animal = Dog;
    } else {
        animal = Wolf;
    }
    animal.bark();
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, but not that easily.  What you've written there is that `animal` should be a variable of type `Barks`, but `Barks` is a trait; a description of an interface.  Traits don't have a statically-defined size, since a type of any size could come along and `impl Barks`. The compiler has no idea how big to make `animal`.

What you need to do is add a layer of indirection.  In this case, you can use `Box`, although you can also use things like `Rc` or plain references:

```rust
fn main() {
    let animal: Box<dyn Barks>;
    
    if 1 == 2 {
        animal = Box::new(Dog);
    } else {
        animal = Box::new(Wolf);
    }
    
    animal.bark();
}
```

Here, I'm allocating the `Dog` or `Wolf` on the heap, then casting that up to a `Box<dyn Barks>`.  This is *kind of* like casting an object to an interface in something like C# or Java, or casting a `Dog*` to a `Barks*` in C++.

An entirely different approach you could also use would be enums.  You could have `enum Animal { Dog, Wolf }` then define an `impl Animal { fn bark(&self) { ... } }`.  Depends on whether you need a completely open-ended set of animals and/or multiple traits.

Finally, note that "kind of" above.  There are various things that don't work as they would in Java/C#/C++.  For example, Rust doesn't have downcasting (you can't go from `Box<dyn Barks>` back to `Box<Dog>`, or from one trait to another).  Also, this only works if the trait is "object safe" (no generics, no using `self` or `Self` by-value).

Comment: Thanks! You mentioned I could use plain references. How might that work?

Comment: See my answer for plain references.

Answer (score 21):

DK has a good explanation, I'll just chime in with an example where we allocate the `Dog` or `Wolf` on the stack, avoiding a heap allocation:

```rust
fn main() {
    let dog;
    let wolf;
    
    let animal: &dyn Barks = if 1 == 2 {
        dog = Dog;
        &dog
    } else {
        wolf = Wolf;
        &wolf
    };
    
    animal.bark();
}
```

It's a bit ugly, but the references accomplish the same indirection as a `Box` with a smidge less overhead.

See also:

- [How can I conditionally provide a default reference without performing unnecessary computation when it isn't used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58559969/155423)
- [How do I make format! return a &str from a conditional expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54222905/155423)

Answer (score 5):

Defining a custom enumeration is the most efficient way to do this. This will allow you to allocate on the stack exactly the amount of space you need, i.e. the size of the largest option, plus 1 extra byte to track which option is stored. It also allows direct access without a level of indirection, unlike solutions using a `Box` or a trait reference.

Unfortunately, it does require more boiler-plate:

```
enum WolfOrDog {
    IsDog(Dog),
    IsWolf(Wolf)
}
use WolfOrDog::*;

impl Barks for WolfOrDog {
    fn bark(&self) {
        match *self {
            IsDog(ref d) => d.bark(),
            IsWolf(ref w) => w.bark()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let animal: WolfOrDog;
    if 1 == 2 {
        animal = IsDog(Dog);
    } else {
        animal = IsWolf(Wolf);
    }
    animal.bark();
}
```

In `main` we use only a single stack allocated variable, holding an instance of our custom enumeration.

Comment: I think that `Canine` would be better name for enum.