# What does a lifetime mean when returning a conservative impl trait?

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime

When searching for documentation about *conservative impl trait*, [I found this example](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43719):

```
struct A {
    x: [(u32, u32); 10]
}

impl A {
    fn iter_values<'a>(&'a self) -> impl 'a + Iterator<Item = u32> {
        self.x.iter().map(|a| a.0)
    }
}
```

What does the lifetime `'a` mean in the return type?

I am aware of [this question about lifetime bound in `Box`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028470/why-is-adding-a-lifetime-to-a-trait-with-the-plus-operator-iteratoritem-foo), but I think that the usecases are different. If I understand well the answer:

> trait object is only valid for the lifetime 'a

It means that the trait object that lives somewhere in the heap will last during a lifetime `'a`.

But here, this is not a trait object but a concrete object that lives in the stack. So the compiler does not need to have hints about its lifetime.

What am I missing about this?

Comment: It means pretty much the same as when you see a lifetime in any bound. e.g. `T: 'a + Debug`.

Comment: @PeterHall If I understand well this notation, it is needed when we use a reference to `T` somewhere. But here, I return a concrete `struct` that implements `Iterator`.

Comment: It would be unfair of the borrow-checker to reason about the code using any information that a human reader wouldn't also have access to. While the concrete type is known inside the function, it is not known outside.

Answer (score 13):

The syntax `impl Iterator<Item = u32> + 'a` means

- some type defined by the function will be returned, but you do not know the exact type. That's the `impl ...` part.
- the unspecified concrete type will be an iterator of `u32` values. That's the `Iterator<Item = u32>` part.
- the unspecified concrete type **may contain references** with the lifetime `'a`. That's the `+ 'a` part.

In your example, the returned iterator contains references to `self`, so it must not be allowed to live longer than the instance of `A`, otherwise it would be invalid. The concrete type (if we could write it) would be `iter::Map<slice::Iter<'a, (u32, u32)>, <closure>>` — note that it has a `'a` in it.

> It means that the trait object that lives somewhere in the heap will last during a lifetime `'a`.

This is not quite true. Both cases have the same meaning: the unspecified concrete type may contain a reference. With a trait object, the concrete type is behind a pointer of some kind (`Box`, `&`, `Rc`, etc.). With impl trait, the concrete type is placed directly on the stack.

> this is not a trait object but a concrete object that lives in the stack

Trait objects do not require the heap; they can utilize only the stack:

```
let x: &std::fmt::Display = &42;
println!("{}", x);
```

See also:

- [Why are explicit lifetimes needed in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31609137/155423)
- [Are polymorphic variables allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28219519/155423)

Comment: _"may contain references with the lifetime 'a"_  — Interesting that you phrased it that way. Completely equivalent, but my intuition of its meaning is the contrapositive: "must not outlive the lifetime 'a".

Answer (score 3):

> It means that the trait object that lives somewhere in the heap will last during a lifetime `'a`.

Not quite.

`'a` here does not exactly specify, it only places an upper-bound on the lifetime of the object. Whether the object is located on the heap or on the stack does not matter: the compiler must ensure that the lifetime of this object does not exceed `'a`.

The lifetime represents a relationship between referred and referent, and is used to ensure that the referent will never outlive the referred. As such, it places an upper-bound on the lifetime of the referent and a lower-bound on the lifetime of the referred.

---

The compiler *could* derive the necessary lifetime from the actual concrete type that is returned by the function, however it would require that the type-checker be able to look at the function implementation to perform its job.

Documenting the lifetime constraint at the interface boundary is thus more friendly to both humans and compiler: it allows local reasoning.